# Multilanguage in quick access toolbar(mfc)

Tags: c++, mfc, multilingual

I'm implementing a multilanguage functionality in an mfc project. Everything's fine, but I don't know how to translate the built-in options in the QAT(More commands, Show above the ribbon etc...) Is it actually possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

This is located in the MFC language files. Also the MFC DLLs have satelite DLLs.

When you link statically you need to include the specific AFX/MFC resources from your VS folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio nnn\VC\atlmfc\include

You find subfolders for l.deu (German) and others.

EDIT:

If you are not able to use the staeltite DLLs you get acces to the QAT with the GetQuickAccessCommands function. You get a list of IDs that are defined in the QAT. Remember that this commands are already located in the ribbon.

With GetElementsByID you are able to get an array pointers to the ribbon elements.

Comment: These are the needed languages: German,
Englisch,
Norwegian,
Finnian,
Spanisch,
French,
Italian,
Dutch,
Swedish,
Portuguese,
Polish,
Hungarian,
Serbian. Lots of them are missing from this directory :/

Comment: Than create your own language DLL... I had to do that for Turkish and Hungarian.

Comment: I forgot to say something important - I need to translate the menus dynamicly. So... is the same technique applicable or should I find a way to access them by ID and set new strings?

Comment: Easier is to use a satellite DLL and use SetResourceHandle. That is the recommended way in MFC:

Comment: OK, I think I got the concept and I pretty much like it. BUT there's a problem - I'm working on a project someone else in the company started long ago. They use a custom function to translate the menus etc. So I need to use the existing code. Also everything is split in different files which makes it even harder to implements the satellite DLL method. So, in this case it seems the easiest way is to find these items' IDs. But how is this accomplished? I can't find info anywhere. I only know I should be somehow able to get a pointer to the QAT and access it's items by ID :/

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what what I need. Still I'll have to find the exact IDs but I guess this should be the way :)